# Docker container not restarting on health check failures

Tags: docker, docker-compose, health-monitoring

I have the following `docker-compose` file

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  myservice:
    restart: always
    image: myimage
    hostname: myhost
    env_file:
      - ./env/common.env
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl --silent --fail localhost:9091/status || exit 1"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 1s
      retries: 1
      start_period: 5s   
    ports:
      - 27018:27018
    volumes: 
      - type: bind
        source: ./scripts/myservice
        target: /scripts  
    entrypoint: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "apk add bash && chmod a+x /scripts/init.sh && /scripts/init.sh"]
```

On running `docker-compose run myservice`, my container starts correctly (it doesn't crash).
However, the health check is failing and when I do a `docker ps`, I can see that the container is unhealthy.

I want the container to restart automatically on when the container is unhealthy, however the container throws an error in the logs and continues to run when the `curl` call is made.

How can I make sure that my container is restarted when the health check fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to have a look for [this](https://github.com/willfarrell/docker-autoheal), its functions as next:

> Monitor and restart unhealthy docker containers. This functionality was proposed to be included with the addition of HEALTHCHECK, however didn't make the cut. This container is a stand-in till there is native support for --exit-on-unhealthy https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/22719.

For your case, you could setup a monitor container with above support like next, this container could monitor all unhealthy container and restart them for you.

```
docker run -d \
    --name autoheal \
    --restart=always \
    -e AUTOHEAL_CONTAINER_LABEL=all \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    willfarrell/autoheal
```

Comment: ok, looks like it only gets restarted in swarm mode based on health checks. Thanks!